# How to rewrite pandas to sql

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql

Want to rewrite pandas code to sql. Have the following code:

```
new = (
    personal
    .sort_values
    (
        ['name','lastname','age']
        , ascending = False
    )
    .drop_duplicates(['id'])
)
```

Here is how I wrote in sql:

```
(SELECT 
     *, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            Partition by id
            ORDER BY 
                name DESC, 
                lastname DESC,
                age DESC
    ) row_num
into  new
     FROM personal);
DELETE FROM  new
WHERE row_num > 1;

ALTER TABLE new
DROP COLUMN row_num;
```

Are those the same functions? cause in result they return few different rows somehow, but I can't understand where is a mistake....

Answer (score 0):

user458!

In this case, if you have duplicates but all parameters are equal (say same name, last name and age), you can just use DISTINCT on the SELECT statement as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    id,
    name,
    lastname,
    age
FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 3 DESC, 4 DESC
```

Check this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5gRNrwr2quJR7CVAcaMvM9/2) for clarity, but it's pretty straightforward :)

Comment: but if not all parameters are equal?

Comment: let's use an example and work from there. you can use the db fiddle I linked in my post, and see that there are duplicates in there :)